# How can I draw the activity diagram that has the same activity?

Tags: uml, activity-diagram

I want to draw an activity diagram that includes two swimlane (Responsible for Education, Training Manager and Education System). That the activity diagram of the route were similar, But they are separated from the middle of the route.

Please see the picture below.

[image]

These activities **Give a score** , **Verify scores** are done by Training Manager and This activity **Edit request** is done by Responsible for Education.

How can I draw the right activity diagram?

Is the activity diagram displayed correctly?

Thank you for giving me suggestions.

Comment: Add another swimlane and move those two activities to that swimlane. Whether or not it is correct: we cannot answer this. I do suspect though that the "View ... form" activities should be renamed to "Show ... form" or they should be moved to another swimlane.

Comment: I fixed the picture, thanks a lot.

Comment: There is a flaw when merging the paths at the action "Displays Access denied message". It shall be merged before connecting to this action, otherwise, the execution gets stuck at this action, as it waits for a token on the second connector.

Comment: @sim No, that's not true. Only a fork/join will wait for all tokens to continue. A simple action will commence upon receipt of a single token. Further, there is only one token on the way which could reach the mentioned action.There's also no "token joining" of you connect two information flows.

Comment: Of yourse that's true. An action (or executable node, in general) shall not execute until there is a token on each incomming control flow (if there is any). This is not an "token joining" it is an implicit join of control flows.

Comment: @sim If you say so, this is self evident for sure.